# Can I add a form application to my C++ console application

Tags: c++, winforms

I have a C++ console application. I do some operations with keys. Do I have a chance to do these operations on the button by adding a form application?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: A regular windows form application

I want to dump some of the operations I've done in the console application into a windows form application

Comment: I'm downloading files or something from the internet, but I want them to be done when the button is pressed using c++ language.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a separate MFC application which uses c++ only and windows classes, then you can integrate all classes from Console application to it ...

- or -

change  subsystem in visual studio to subsystem: windows from console, by going to project properties of course. then create a win32 windows with controls on it ...

ya got two ways ...

Comment: Why can't I open a new form file over my existing console application?

Comment: forms have certain minimum dependencies, console are so vanilla neat  and clean ... ya need to include some stuff for forms ....

Comment: Is there a resource for this? A resource where I can add a windows form on top of an existing console application